# Food souvenir purchasable in dubai

Tags: food-and-drink, dubai, uae, dxb, souvenirs

Since I have half day stopover in Dubai, I want to go out of the airport and buy some food souvenir for my family.

Date is common Arabic sweet but I am not interested in, similarly I don’t interested in candy like chocolate.

May anyone advice non-candy and non-sweet Arabic food suitable for souvenir purchasable? And where can I buy in Dubai?

Comment: You can get some other arabic sweets; or arabic coffee. However, your question itself is very broad as there are tons of things you can buy when it comes to food souvenirs in Dubai; from sweets, coffee all the way to spices.

Comment: Yeah but one really doesn't expect to bring succulent mangoes or coconuts from Dubai - but where else can you get [camel milk chocolate](http://www.al-nassma.com/)?

Comment: @burhan khaild no chocolate plz

Comment: Many countries have restrictions on what fresh food you can bring in from outside, eg [EU rules restrict brining in meat and dairy products](http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/common/travellers/enter_eu/index_en.htm). Make sure you're allowed to enter your destination country with the food you buy!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I thought I would complement this answer that is already quite good! The Deira Spice Souk is obviously an inescapable area in Dubai. You'll find there all you need to cook almost anything.

Then, as you said in your original message, dates are really good there.

Another thing that is typical of the area is the honey and especially the Yemeni honey. You can find some in Dubai Mall and I am sure you'll be delighted with it. It is among the best (and also most expensive) around the world. The taste is pretty strong and it is well known to have a lot of benefits for the healthcare.

Beside honey, spice and dates, you might want to bring back some local arab cookies. Those are delicious, made with honey, almonds, etc... All you need to have a good time :)

You can find [more details about Dubai souvenirs in this post](http://www.olielo.com/what-to-buy-in-dubai/).

Answer (score 7):

I found the Deira Spice Souk very interesting. It's an [easy metro ride from the airport](https://www.google.de/maps/dir/DXB+-+Dubai+-+United+Arab+Emirates/Deira+Spice+Souk+-+D85+-+Dubai/@25.2623578,55.3112474,14z/data=!4m15!4m14!1m5!1m1!1s0x3e5f5d0693260e69:0xe695d4007a48eee9!2m2!1d55.3656728!2d25.2531745!1m5!1m1!1s0x3e5f4341272261e1:0xb3f1fde2ec342f19!2m2!1d55.2968548!2d25.2673553!3e3!5i1). I considered picking up some gifts there for family, but ended up not doing so. If you have cooks in your family they might appreciate some of the unique spices offered here.

[image]

Comment: Do they accept card?

Comment: Good question. Since I didn't purchase anything I don't know for sure, but there are many vendors and I am confident some of them accept cards.